# Heroku gives me a CORS issue, but only after 20 mins of deploying. Before that, everything works fine

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, heroku

Hosting my first Node JS backend on Heroku today and ran into a weird issue. When I try to register/login right after deploying the backend, things work very smoothly, but if I try to register/login after about 15 minutes, I receive a CORS error. (I am using the cors dependency).

Here's my server code:

```
const express = require('express')
const mysql = require('mysql')
const cors = require('cors')
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt')
const app = express()
const saltRounds = 10

app.use(cors())
app.use(express.json())

app.post('/signup', (req, res) => {
const username = req.body.username
const password = req.body.password

bcrypt.hash(password, saltRounds, (err, hash) => {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err)
    }
    db.query("INSERT INTO users (username, password) VALUES (?, ?)", [username, hash], 
    (err, result) => {
        console.log(err)
    })
})
})

app.post('/login', (req, res) => {
    const username = req.body.username
    const password = req.body.password

    db.query("SELECT * FROM  users WHERE username = ?", [username], (err, result) => {
        if (err) {
            res.send({err: err})
        } 
        if (result.length > 0) {
            bcrypt.compare(password, result[0].password, (err, response) => {
                if (response) {
                    res.send(result)
                } else{
                    res.send({message: "Invalid Credentials"})
                    }
            })
        } else {
        res.send({message: "User does not exist."})
        }
    
})
```

})

Apologies if my code is formatted a bit strange, I always struggle with StackOverflow's code format.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out! mysql was timing out because I was using createConnection instead of createPool on my server.js. Hope this helps someone in the future!